# How to make a JavaFX textfield not visible but still allow text to be entered into it

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a javaFX application which takes input from a barcode scanner. The barcode scanner is recognised as a keyboard and always follows its input with a newline after any barcode is scanned (so onAction event is triggered).

At the moment I have a textfield which is always focused and linked to the barcode scanner, however I would like this to be hidden from the user. I tried using setVisible(False) but this seems to disable the textfield (onAction isn't triggered and textfield always empty)

I also tried putting the textfield off the screen which did work however because the screen has to be resizable I now have to use gridPane as the root so its not possible to do this anymore.

Just wondering if there is anyway to make the textfield invisible to the user but still allow it to be enabled?

Comment: Have you considered using a JLabel instead of a TextField if the data can only be editable from the barcode scanner?

Also you can always override the paint() method to achieve such things...

Comment: @SomerandomITboy Your thinking of the swing library I think, I don't think javafx nodes have a paint() method do they? Also I found a work around, I'm aware this is probably bad but for now I just set the opacity of the textfield to 0 within its css property. It will do for now I guess :D

Comment: Yeah, but I mean that you can always override the method that takes care of the painting of the visual component. Also there has to be an equivalent of the JLabel for JavaFX

Comment: @SomerandomITboy In JavaFX one doesn't have direct control of the painting mechanism—at least not in the same way as in Swing. Instead, we just configure various properties (some of which are "automatically" configured by a layout) which causes a "pulse" to be scheduled which handles the rendering.

Comment: why use a textfield, to start with? you could intercept keyEvents with an eventFilter on any higher up parent in the scenegraph

Comment: This feels like an x-y-problem, so please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what you are doing and why you think a textField is a solution to what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few possibilities to hide the text field using css. The easiest is to set the opacity to 0

**TextField.css**

```
.hidden{
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

Java

```
GridPane root = new GridPane();
// Add stylesheet
root.getStylesheets().add("TextField.css");

TextField textField = new TextField();
// Add class
textField.getStyleClass().add("hidden");
```

On the other hand I would really ask myself if this "hack" is the way to go. If your barcode scanner is simply inserting text, maybe the better solution is to add an event handler and handle the keystrokes accordingly:

EventHandler

```
root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY,(event)->{
    System.out.println(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need to have a `TextField` in the scene. In fact I wouldn't recommend doing that, since this would interfere with the focus and possibly the layout.

Instead I'd add a listener to the scene (or the root node of the scene making sure it or a descendant can get focus by setting the `focusTraversable` property to `true`, if necessary). You may need to use a event filter, if a node that consumes the `KEY_PRESSED` may have focus:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    StackPane root = new StackPane(new Button());
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    final StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, evt -> {
        KeyCode code = evt.getCode();
        if (code.isDigitKey()) {
            // input part of the information
            String name = code.toString();
            string.append(name.charAt(name.length() - 1)); // make sure numpad keys do not 
        } else if (code == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            // submit input
            submitCode(string.toString());
            string.setLength(0);
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void submitCode(String code) {
    System.out.println(code);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [TextField.setText(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText(java.lang.String)).

Comment: no, the problem is that the scanner input plays the role of a Keyboard, that is delivering its scanresults via keyEvents which are delivererd to the focusOwner which must be a visible node